# App doesn't require SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission to draw overlay

Tags: android, firebase, permissions, overlay, malware

For my thesis I'm analyzing several samples of malware, such as Crypto (com.crypto.theapp) as well as Flashlight Widget (com.flashscary.widget), both of which use overlays to display fake login screens. Neither of those require SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission grant though, which is supposedly required for drawing on top on an overlay. Both of them however have permission necessary for communicating with outside server via Fireabse (com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE and packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE). Could anyone please explain to me how is it possible to display an overlay in spite of not having the SAW permission? I read a couple articles, but all they say is that that malware uses the mentioned outside server to display the overlay.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Android are you observing this behavior on?

Comment: "Neither of those require SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission grant" -- do you mean that they do not have the `<uses-permission>` element? Do you mean that the user did not have to manually grant access to that permission via Settings? Do you mean something else? Also, please explain in programming terms what you mean by "overlays" in this context.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well this malware surely works up to Android N, sot sure about Oreo though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah this permission isn't in the manifest and the malware doesn't ask the user for this permission. I am not sure about the nature of this overlay, it's just a window that covers the entire screen with a fake login screen.

Comment: Does the apps you are investigating use the techniques described in this article: https://www.welivesecurity.com/2017/04/19/turn-light-give-passwords/ Starting with `As soon as the app is installed and launched, it requests device administrator rights.`

Comment: "I am not sure about the nature of this overlay, it's just a window that covers the entire screen with a fake login screen" -- perhaps it is an activity.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I launched it in an emulator and it actually does ( https://imgur.com/a/HnFHc ) But there come new questions.

1. How can it ask to draw on top of the screen without having the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission in the manifest?

2. About the second screen about permitting usage access - I wonder how it works so that it could be detected by analyzing an installed app? I am developing a small app that analyzes other apps features such as permissions, activities etc, using stuff like PackageManager and ApplicationInfo. Is there any way to detect that an app requires such rights?

Comment: if u able to list apllication in app with PackageManager u can list requested permission for each app in system